# Build task to set 'Build Action' to 'None' to automatically exclude debug CSS/JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

My web application project contains a various CSS and JavaScript files around the place, for example demo.debug.css and demo.debug.js.

On build, these files are all minified to demo.css or demo.js for example.

Many of the *.debug.css/*.debug.js files have their build action set to 'None' to ensure they are not included in the Published project, only the minified files are output as their build action is set to 'Content'.

What I want is a build task or action that will automatically scan the project and set this build action value to None, so as new files are added, they are not included by default.

The followiing was added to a build task, but 'None' was not a valid task name.

```
<None Include="**\*.debug.css" />
```

So I added this to the project file, but this duplicated all the affected files in Visual Studios Solution Explorer.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="**\*.debug.css" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I suspect I need a reference added to the build task, but can't find the where this task assembly is located. Neither of my two options set the build action of the files at any point.